# Git: Replace a file tracked by git with another file with the same name

Tags: git

I cloned a Git repo on my laptop and for some reason, I had to replace some files in it from another folder that is not managed by git but contains the same files.

Example:

> Git repo (cloned in my hard drive)
>
> File1.ts
>
> File2.ts
>
> File3.ts
>
> Another folder in my hard drive
>
> File1.ts
>
> File2.ts
>
> File3.ts

When I replaced "normal files" with the ones tracked by git. Git created duplicated files "_.". My commit has become like this.

> File1.ts
>
> File2.ts
>
> File3.ts
>
> ._File1.ts
>
> ._File2.ts
>
> _File3.ts

My question is: How to replace a file tracked by git with another ordinary file that has the same  name and get the same behavior as a modified file

Comment: How exactly did you "replace" the files? I highly doubt that Git created those files.

Comment: You're right. I did a copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Coping the "normal' file over the tracked file is sufficient.  That is, `git` does not know *how* the contents of a file changed.  You can use any tool - including a simple file copy - to change what's in the file, and it just works.  That's the purpose of the working copy.

At what point did the new files appear?  Is there a particular git command you ran, before which you checked and did not see the files, but after which you checked and did see the files?  The reason I ask is, although you say git created the files, it isn't something git does - so it might help to better understand when the files were created.

Given only what we know from this post, it sounds like whatever copy/paste tool you used on the files was trying to avoid data loss by manipulating filenames of either the original files or the ones copied in.  I don't know a system that does it in quite the way you described, but then I also don't know what system you're using.